# Subclassing XCTestCase subclasses: Test Navigator does not show all tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, xctest

I'm new to subclassing XCTestCase on multiple levels, but was curious to trying it out since it could potentially save me lots of time rewriting tests, so I set up a simple hierarchy of classes in my testing target:

```
BaseSpriteNodeTests : XCTestCase
 -> CharacterTests : BaseSpriteNodeTests
 -> -> EnemyTests : CharacterTests
 -> -> PlayerTests : CharacterTests
```

I gave `BaseSpriteNodeTests` two simple test methods: `testCreation` and `testDestroy`, to see the how inheritance is handled inside test targets.

When I `Cmd+U` all the tests, the console output is expected. (4 total classes, two methods each, 8 tests total)

```
Test Suite 'All tests' passed at 2015-09-21 09:43:46.396.
     Executed 8 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.217 (0.225) seconds
```

However, the Test Navigator is only showing 7 tests:

[image: Test Navigator]

Is this a bug in Xcode, or am I missing something crucial about subclassing XCTestCase subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36729522/818054) - try deleting DerivedData.

I believe this is indeed an Xcode bug. Test Navigator, like a few other Xcode features, has a tendency to fall out of step with reality as changes are made. The only way to recover is to force a rebuild of the relevant index files/memory.